# Express: The requested module does not provide an export named 'User'

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6, database-schema

I am using **Nodemon** and ESM module to use ES6 syntax on a **Express** + **Mongoose** project. I am getting this error when compiling:

> **SyntaxError**: The requested module 'file:///.../models/User.js' does not provide an export named 'User'

My model file (models/User.js) looks like this:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  type: String,
  createdOn: String,
  updatedOn: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = { User };
```

And then I import it:

```
import { User } from '../models/User';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export default {
    Query: {
        getUsers: async () => await User.find({}).exec()
    },
    Mutation: {
        addUser: async (_, args) => {
            try {
                const user = args;
                user.password = await hashPassword(args.password);
                user.createdOn = Date.now();
                user.updatedOn = Date.now();

                let response = await User.create(user);
                return response;

            } catch(e) {
                return e.message;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I was following [this guide](https://medium.com/@williamyang93/graphql-apollo-mongodb-mongoose-part-i-a727bb22f1f6), but he uses ES5 syntax. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are mixing **ES6 modules** (`import, export`) with **CommonJS** (`require/module.exports`). We are going to need to replace `module.exports = { User };` with `export const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);` in order to succesfully import it as an ES6 module in your other file. You can create a named export in your model file as follows:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  type: String,
  createdOn: String,
  updatedOn: String
});

export const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Which will then allow you to import like this:

```
import { User } from '../models/User';
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you.